# f:setPropertyActionListener not invoked

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am trying to move a `p:dialog` out of a `h:form`, because I have read that this is the preferred way (however I'd like to understand the reason, because my `p:dialog` inside a `form` works well in my application).

The only difficulty is that the dialog title needs to be updated dynamically. The dialog is shown when a button in a `p:dataTable` is clicked.

Here is my old xhtml (before the changes), that's working fine:

```
<p:dataTable var="event" value="#{eventBean.lazyModel}" selection="#{eventBean.selectedEvent}" />
    ...
    <p:column headerText="#{msgs.Persons}">
        <p:commandButton value="#{msgs.ViewPersons}" update=":viewPersonsForm" oncomplete="viewPersonsDlg.show()"> 
            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{event}" target="#{eventBean.selectedEvent}" />
        </p:commandButton>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
<h:form id="viewPersonsForm">
    <p:dialog modal="true" widgetVar="viewPersonsDlg" dynamic="true" header="#{eventBean.selectedEvent.name}" >
        ...
    </p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

And here is the new xhtml, with eventBean#setSelectedEvent() that is not invoked.

```
<p:dataTable var="event" value="#{eventBean.lazyModel}" selection="#{eventBean.selectedEvent}" />
    ...
    <p:column headerText="#{msgs.Persons}">
        <p:commandButton value="#{msgs.ViewPersons}" update=":viewPersonsDlgId" oncomplete="jQuery('#viewPersonsDlgId .ui-dialog-title').text('#{eventBean.selectedEvent.name}');viewPersonsDlg.show()"> 
            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{event}" target="#{eventBean.selectedEvent}" />
        </p:commandButton>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
<p:dialog modal="true" id="viewPersonsDlgId" widgetVar="viewPersonsDlg" dynamic="true" >
    ...
</p:dialog>
```

So, again, why in the second scenario eventBean#setSelectedEvent() is not invoked? And, if possible, why the first scenario is not optimal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not restricted to use `p:dialog` inside a `h:form` since it can work in some cases, but most of the time you will find yourself struggling with some unexpected behaviour with that, here are some explanations :

[Why not to place `p:dialog` inside `h:form` 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10579708/1317692)

[Why not to place `p:dialog` inside `h:form` 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10028815/1317692)

The problem in your case is that jQuery method in `oncomplete` is called before the value is set with `f:setPropertyActionListener`. To avoid this use the same solution as you used in your first case. So :

```
<p:dataTable var="event" value="#{eventBean.lazyModel}" selection="#{eventBean.selectedEvent}" />
    ...
    <p:column headerText="#{msgs.Persons}">
        <p:commandButton value="#{msgs.ViewPersons}" update=":viewPersonsDlgId" oncomplete="viewPersonsDlg.show()"> 
            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{event}" target="#{eventBean.selectedEvent}" />
        </p:commandButton>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
<p:dialog modal="true" id="viewPersonsDlgId" widgetVar="viewPersonsDlg" dynamic="true" header="#{eventBean.selectedEvent.name}" >
    ...
</p:dialog>
```

No need to use jQuery here.

Comment: Thanks for the links. Unfortunately the setter isn't fired even with your setup.

Comment: I've tested it and it is working fine. If the setter is not fired for you, then one of JSF cycle phase failed. Add `<h:messages>` to your page and check for errors.

Comment: Awesome, it solved my problem as well :). Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem (pf 3.5):

```
<p:tabView id="cashFlowTabContainer" style="width:100%" activeIndex="0"
    widgetVar="cashFlowTabContainerVar">
    <p:tab title="#{labels['cashflow_incoming']}">
        <p:outputPanel id="incomingPanel">
            <p:dataTable value="#{cashFlowController.incomingCashFlows}"
                var="cashFlow">
<p:column headerText="#{labels.cashflow_actions}">
                    <p:commandButton value="Edit"
                        action="#    {cashFlowController.editIncoming}" update="@form" oncomplete="editInputVar.show();">
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener     value="#{cashFlow}"
                            target="#{cashFlowController.selectedIncoming}" />
                    </p:commandButton>
                </p:column>
```

and this was my dialog:

```
<p:dialog id="editInput" header="Dynamic Dialog"
    widgetVar="editInputVar" resizable="false" draggable="false"
    modal="true">
    <p:panel>
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">
...
<h:outputText value="#{labels.cashflow_description}:" />
            <h:inputText
                value="#{cashFlowController.selectedIncoming.description}" />
```

So... This way the setter was NEVER called. Then I noticed that if I emptied the dialog the setter was called.

So I solved it by putting a "rendered" statement on the panel:

```
<p:dialog id="editInput" header="Dynamic Dialog"
    widgetVar="editInputVar" resizable="false" draggable="false"
    modal="true">
    <p:panel **rendered="#{cashFlowController.selectedIncoming != null}"**>
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">
```

I guess there's a null pointer that is not logged anywhere... anyway this way it works :)